# How can fixed side navbar fit parent div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap:

I have a left side navbar (col-sm-2) and right content part (col-sm-10).

I want to make the left side navbar fixed on the screen,

However, once I add the "position: fixed" there, the navbar becomes smaller.

```css
.row.content {
  height: 1500px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.navigationDiv {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: pink; // color should be #f1f1f1; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">

      <div class="navigationDiv">

        <h4 class="text-center">Jimmy's Blog</h4>

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active navbar-btn text-center"><a href="">    Home        </a></li>
          <li class="navbar-btn text-center"><a href="">  Photo Gallery        </a></li>
          <li class="navbar-btn text-center"><a href="">  Blog Log          </a></li>
          <li class="navbar-btn text-center"><a href="">  About Me            </a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <p>sdkjflksadjflk;sjadkl;jsdlak;jflk;sdjfl;ksjlfjks;ajfkl;sajdfljsdaklfls;adjflksdjfl;;fj<br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br>sdkjflksadjflk;sjadkl;jsdlak;jflk;sdjfl;ksjlfjks;ajfkl;sajdfljsdaklfls;adjflksdjfl;;fj<br><br>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the navigationDiv fit the parent sidenav?

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32316/)

Comment: Which browser do you use? I use Chrome and there is no such issue when I add `position:fixed` in the navbar.

Comment: @Bla...        Did you check my jsfiddle? I use Chrome.

Comment: add html{min-height: 100%} and body {height: 100%}

Comment: @Patrick My bad. Okay, have you tried adding `width: 100%;` into `.navigationDiv`? I'm not sure if that's what you want. :)

Comment: @Bla...        I tried it before, the side navbar covers whole screen.